# How to pause and resume fadeIn() from opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity, fadein, resume

I'm trying to resume a fadeIn() from the opacity where it paused. 
I have two draggables. If the one is dropped (I called it draggable_purple), a purple div starts to fade in. Only to a specific opacity. When the opacity has been reached, another div appears (lightblue) with a message to drop the yellow-draggable. After the yellow-draggable has been dropped, I want the purple div to proceed the fadeIn.

It might sound a bit far fetched and excuse me for my code, I tried to narrow it down to the only elements that matter in this case.

In the JsFiddle you'll find my solution, but it doesn't work. My question to you is; How would you solve this and why isn't my own solution working. Thank you for your time in advance.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr9d7/)

**jQuery**

```
$("#draggable_purple").draggable({
    revert: true
});


$("#draggable_yellow").draggable({
    revert: true
});

$("#orange").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.is('#draggable_purple')) {
            $(this).parent().find('#purple').fadeTo(1500, 0.5, onhold);

            $(this).droppable('destroy');
        }
    }
});


function onhold() {
    $(this).parent().find('#lightblue').show();
}

$('#lightblue').droppable({
    accept: '#draggable_yellow',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).hide('fast'); $('#purple').css('opacity', 0.5).fadeIn(1500, 1.5);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="orange">
         <div id="purple">
          </div>
        <div id="lightblue"> Drop the yellow div,
            to continue the fadeIn
          </div>
          </div>

 <div id="draggable_purple"> start purple fadeIn
          </div>
 <div id="draggable_yellow"> resume fadeIn
          </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, did you say there is a jsFiddle to go with this.

Comment: @Bruno My bad sorry, it's up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#purple').css('opacity', 0.5).fadeIn(1500, 1.5);
```

To this:

```
$('#purple').fadeTo(1500, 1);
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opoe/Nr9d7/)

---

**Another thing**, this line:

```
$(this).parent().find('#purple').fadeTo(1500, 0.5, onhold);
```

Is pointless. You have the `id`, it's *unique*, there is no need for `parent` and `find`:

```
$('#purple').fadeTo(1500, 0.5, onhold);
```

Comment: You're right about the code, I narrowed it down, some lines may still be far fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Good solid pause/resume is surprisingly tricky but - good news - there's a jQuery **[plugin](http://tobia.github.com/Pause/)** to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.fadeIn` in the yellow method instead of `.fadeTo` (I'm not sure why you have `1.5` either .. I think `1` will do).